# how to update ObservableCollection<> of one page from another page in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, observablecollection

My application is in MVVM architecture.

I Have photo.xaml page in which i have one 1 ListView whoose bindingcontext is ObservableCollection listphoto  of photos  which is defined in its viewmodel.cs file.

now i have  to redirect to BarcodeScan.cs from button click of photo.xaml .

my que i how  can i add item to listphoto from here(BarcodeScan.cs )??

I tried to define new list in BarcodeScan like this

```
  public ObservableCollection<JobPhoto> ListSerialNumbers { get; set; }
```

and intialised in its constructor like this

```
ListSerialNumbers = new ObservableCollection<JobPhoto>();
```

but it dont update list on photo.xaml page.

how can i achieve this. I am new to MVVM.Please Help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use messaging center for this

First get it method registered as :

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<YourObjectClassComesHere>(this, "Any Message or empty string will be okay", (Obj) =>
            {
                //Code you want to execute
            });
```

After this you can invoke it from another page as

```
MessagingCenter.Send(YourObject(of type "YourObjectClassComesHere"), "Any Message or empty string will be okay");
```

Hope it helps.

More details are available at : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/

Answer (score 1):

You can try MessageCenter https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/

In Phonepage you subscript message and send a message from another page.

Comment: isnt it only for passign message?

Answer (score 0):

> I Have photo.xaml page in which i have one 1 ListView whoose bindingcontext is ObservableCollection listphoto of photos which is defined in its viewmodel.cs file.

Firstly it would be worth showing your XAML code.

You say in the quote above that you set the bindingcontext of the listview to the collection. You should be setting the ItemSource property of the ListView to the collection.